# There are problems with Mac OS + Python3.6 + PyQt5 + pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Mac OS uses pyinstaller to wrap PyQt5's app. After clicking the button, the program flashes back (no terminal) and prompts the program to crash, and the resolution is not clear.
When I run the exec file generated by pyinstaller, the program can run normally, and the resolution is very clear.

Have anyone ever been in the same situation? This is a problem that bothers me for 2 days..

On the left is the program opened by exec and the program opened by app on the right.

[image]